# Hidden table row does not display where it is supposed to

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is supposed to display additional information in a hidden row for each row in my table.

The problem is, it is not being displayed under the row itself but rather above the table.
So if I select row 3 to view its additional information, the hidden row should appear under it but instead it is appearing on the top of all the rows.

I'm guessing there's something wrong with my table structure but I can't figure out what.

And here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypuEj/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://drvic10k.github.io/bootstrap-sortable/Contents/bootstrap-sortable.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://drvic10k.github.io/bootstrap-sortable/Scripts/bootstrap-sortable.js"></script>
<script src="http://drvic10k.github.io/bootstrap-sortable/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});

</script>

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title">View Listings</h3>
        <div class="box-tools">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control input-sm pull-right" style="width: 150px;" placeholder="Search">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped sortable" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-defaultsort="asc" data-sortcolumn="0" data-sortkey="0-1">ID</th>
                        <th data-defaultsign="month" data-sortcolumn="1" data-sortkey="1-1">Status</th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="2" data-sortkey="2-1">For</th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="3" data-sortkey="3-1">Availability</th>
                        <th data-mainsort="true" data-sortcolumn="4" data-sortkey="4-1">Type<span class="sign arrow"></span></th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="5" data-sortkey="5-1">Contact</th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="6" data-sortkey="6-1">Reference ID</th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="7" data-sortkey="7-1">Location</th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="8" data-sortkey="8-1">Category</th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="9" data-sortkey="9-1">Apartment Area</th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="10" data-sortkey="10-1">Garden Area</th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="11" data-sortkey="11-1">Parking</th>
                        <th data-sortcolumn="12" data-sortkey="12-1">Visitors Parking</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($listings as $key => $value)
                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ $value->id }}" class="accordion-toggle">
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->id }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->status }}">{{ $value->status }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->listingfor }}">{{ $value->listingfor }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->propertystatus }}">{{ $value->propertystatus }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->propertytype }}">{{ $value->propertytype }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->contact_id }}">{{ $value->contact_id }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->reference_id }}">{{ $value->reference_id }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->location }}">{{ $value->location }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->category }}">{{ $value->category }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->apartment_area }}">{{ $value->apartment_area }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->garden_area }}">{{ $value->garden_area }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->parking }}">{{ $value->parking }}</td>
                    <td data-value="{{ $value->visitors_parking }}">{{ $value->visitors_parking }}</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('listings/view/' . $value->id) }}">Show</a> <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="{{ URL::to('listings/view/' . $value->id . '/edit') }}">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-small btn-danger" href="{{ URL::to('listings/view/' . $value->id . '/delete') }}">Delete</a></td>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="14" class="hiddenRow">
                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="{{ $value->id }}">
                        <p>Lifestyle: {{ $value->lifestyle }}</p>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to clean up your indenting a bit. This makes it easier to see that you put in an extra ending `</tr>` tag, pretty much the opposite of what @baeda said.

Comment: You were indenting with 4 spaces/tab at the top, but then switched to 2 later. I didn't know which to go with, but I tentatively went with 2. If you don't like it I can change it to 4.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's exactly what @baeda said. He put the table inside the row, though, which makes it all confusing & Inception-y.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show the jQuery or the online hashes (not sure how you can show those in JSFiddle, tbh). Also, how do you hide/reveal the hidden cell? In the fiddle it's hidden but there's no button or anything to reveal it.

Comment: I see you changed the hidden row from `<th>` to `<td>`. That means most of my answer isn't relevant anymore. Also, the table in your fiddle is completely different from the table in your question. The fiddle doesn't have the `show` button you have in your question, to show the hidden row.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your <tr> tag before starting a new row.

```
@foreach($listings as $key => $value)
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ $value->id }}" class="accordion-toggle">
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->id }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->status }}">{{ $value->status }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->listingfor }}">{{ $value->listingfor }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->propertystatus }}">{{ $value->propertystatus }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->propertytype }}">{{ $value->propertytype }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->contact_id }}">{{ $value->contact_id }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->reference_id }}">{{ $value->reference_id }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->location }}">{{ $value->location }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->category }}">{{ $value->category }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->apartment_area }}">{{ $value->apartment_area }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->garden_area }}">{{ $value->garden_area }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->parking }}">{{ $value->parking }}</td>
                <td data-value="{{ $value->visitors_parking }}">{{ $value->visitors_parking }}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('listings/view/' . $value->id) }}">Show</a> <a
                        class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="{{ URL::to('listings/view/' . $value->id . '/edit') }}">Edit</a>
                    <a
                        class="btn btn-small btn-danger"
                        href="{{ URL::to('listings/view/' . $value->id . '/delete') }}">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="14" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="{{ $value->id }}">
                        <p>Lifestyle: {{ $value->lifestyle }}</p>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. The hidden row is still being showed at the top. I didn't forget to close <tr> tag but rather it was meant to be a <tr> within a <tr> but that doesn't work apparently.

Comment: You can't have a <tr> within a <tr> tag. If you want to collapse everything (including the hidden row) you'd need to have a table inside your data-toggle <tr>. I edited my post.

Comment: That didn't work. I already have a table by the way. I edited my post.

Comment: Why did you put a table inside a row/cell? Isn't it supposed to be the other way around? And yes I think you can have a `<tr>` within a `<tr>`. Just harder to make it look right.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you tried to make a row inside your last cell to hold your hidden row. However, you closed out the cell before you made the inside row. Your code is confusing, so I'm not sure if this is the case, but that's what it looks like.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped sortable" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-defaultsort="asc" data-sortcolumn="0" data-sortkey="0-1">ID</th>
            <th data-defaultsign="month" data-sortcolumn="1" data-sortkey="1-1">Status</th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="2" data-sortkey="2-1">For</th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="3" data-sortkey="3-1">Availability</th>
            <th data-mainsort="true" data-sortcolumn="4" data-sortkey="4-1">Type<span class="sign arrow"></span></th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="5" data-sortkey="5-1">Contact</th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="6" data-sortkey="6-1">Reference ID</th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="7" data-sortkey="7-1">Location</th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="8" data-sortkey="8-1">Category</th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="9" data-sortkey="9-1">Apartment Area</th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="10" data-sortkey="10-1">Garden Area</th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="11" data-sortkey="11-1">Parking</th>
            <th data-sortcolumn="12" data-sortkey="12-1">Visitors Parking</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($listings as $key => $value)
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ $value->id }}" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td data-value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->id }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->status }}">{{ $value->status }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->listingfor }}">{{ $value->listingfor }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->propertystatus }}">{{ $value->propertystatus }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->propertytype }}">{{ $value->propertytype }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->contact_id }}">{{ $value->contact_id }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->reference_id }}">{{ $value->reference_id }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->location }}">{{ $value->location }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->category }}">{{ $value->category }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->apartment_area }}">{{ $value->apartment_area }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->garden_area }}">{{ $value->garden_area }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->parking }}">{{ $value->parking }}</td>
            <td data-value="{{ $value->visitors_parking }}">{{ $value->visitors_parking }}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('listings/view/' . $value->id) }}">Show</a> <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="{{ URL::to('listings/view/' . $value->id . '/edit') }}">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-small btn-danger" href="{{ URL::to('listings/view/' . $value->id . '/delete') }}">Delete</a>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="14" class="hiddenRow">
                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="{{ $value->id }}">
                            <p>Lifestyle: {{ $value->lifestyle }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I changed `<th>` to `<td>` in `<tbody>` and now the hidden row is being displayed at the bottom of the table instead of the top. I had to use `<thead>` and `<th>` because of the plugin I'm using to add sorting to my tables, it requires proper table formatting otherwise it won't work.

Comment: So are you saying my answer worked? Sorry, but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, not it didn't work. The hidden row is supposed to show under its parent row and not under the entire table.

Comment: And I am saying because you used a `<th>`, it messed up the `HTML` because `<th>`s are only supposed to be in `<thead>`s. And I still don't understand your comment, did my answer work or not? You say "not it didn't work", but you are not giving any indication it did work.

Comment: So did you fix your problem?

Comment: I didn't really. Have a look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ypuEj/). When you click on the third row, the hidden div should appear under it and not above the table as it is now.

Comment: Can you put that fiddle in your question? That would have been helpful earlier. Can you also put the jQuery for the objects?

Comment: I have updated my post and included the entire page, top to bottom, including JS code. Also added the JS Fiddle link.

Comment: Thank you, it's better. I also found your problem. Will be posting code over the next minute or 2.